# numerical solution for coupled first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How can I numerically solve the below equation, assume I have $K(z)$, the solution is in the $[0,L]$ domain, the conditions are: $A(0)=1, B(L)=1$
$$
1. \frac{dA}{dz} = -K(z)A(z) - K(z)B(z)
$$
$$
2. \frac{dB}{dz} = -K(z)A(z) - K(z)B(z)
$$

Comment: $A(z)-2B(z)=C_0$

Comment: Do you really have identical right hand sides in both equations?  In general, the problem has  boundary values at different points, i.e. it is a boundary value problem, for which for example the shooting method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) or the collocation method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_method) can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can decouple the equations by defining the functions $F=A+B$ and $G=A-B$. Then

$\frac{dF}{dz}=-2K(z)F,\qquad\frac{dG}{dz}=0$,

so that

$F(z)=F_0\exp\left[-2\int_0^z K(t)dt\right],\qquad G(z)=G_0,$

from which follows

$A(z)=\frac{1}{2}F_0\exp\left[-2\int_0^z K(t)dt\right]+\frac{1}{2}G_0, 
\qquad B(z)=\frac{1}{2}F_0\exp\left[-2\int_0^z K(t)dt\right]-\frac{1}{2}G_0.$

In order to determine $F_0$ and $G_0$, we use the boundary conditions
$\left(\xi = e^{-2\int_0^L K(t)dt}\right)$

$A(0) = \frac{1}{2}F_0+\frac{1}{2}G_0 = 1,\qquad 
B(L) = \frac{1}{2}F_0\xi-\frac{1}{2}G_0 = 1$,

which yield

$F_0=\frac{4}{\xi +1}, \qquad G_0=\frac{2(\xi-1)}{\xi+1}.$

Use the numerical method of your choice to compute the integral $\int_0^z K(t)dt$.

Comment: Thank you very much Ricardo, that is very helpful.
By the way if you are intrested in the physical background of this broblem, these equations stem from the coupled mode theory (CMT) of 2 modes (propagate and co-propagate) in a cylindric waveguide.

Comment: This is the first step of the problem, i trying to find a numerical solution for a system of first order coupled ODE, i posted a question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090787/solving-numerically-system-of-first-order-coupled-de-with-non-constant-coefficie).
It will be great if you have something to share over there.